# Link href para id div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Bom sei que conseguimos fazer links direcionando o click `href` para um id da pagina utilizando `#`.

```css
#content1, #content2, #content3, #content4 {
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#content1"> CONTEUDO 1</a>
<a href="#content2"> CONTEUDO 2</a>
<a href="#content3"> CONTEUDO 3</a>
<a href="#content4"> CONTEUDO 4</a>



<div id="content1" class="content1">CONTEUDO 1 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content2" class="content1">CONTEUDO 2 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content3" class="content1">CONTEUDO 3 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content4" class="content1">CONTEUDO 4 TEXTO</div>
```

Desta forma sempre que se clica ele está indo para o `top 0 px`, teria alguma forma de mandar ele para um top diferente, porque dependendo do que tiver no topo, ele irá cortar um pedaço do texto.

Então o ideal seria mudar este top 0, por exemplo para top 5, cara click no link ele leva para o top - 5.

Teria alguma forma de produzir isso ?

Comment: Ou você dexia um padding-top maior nos elementos com CSS ou você utiliza Javascript(jQuery).

Comment: @LeAndrade não necessariamente... com CSS e jeitinho da pra resolver

Comment: Então tava pensando aqui, realmente tem mesmo @hugocsl. Acho até que no caso dele seria melhor só CSS mesmo. Posta aí, se não resolver pra ele eu posto uma com Js.

Comment: @LeAndrade de boa, não é uma técnica muito elegante, mas resolve... Tmj JS tb é opção rss, ainda mais se for sem jQuery =)

Comment: @hugocsl Jóia man.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tudo bem que essa não é uma forma muito "elegante", mas pode resolver apenas com CSS.

A técnica consiste em criar um elemento de `1px` e cor transparente que vai funcionar como uma ancora oculta, com o `position: absolute` vc vai tirar esse elemento do fluxo da página e ele não vai interferir nos outros elementos. Então a ancora será nesse elemento oculto que está `50px` antes do conteúdo que vc quer chamar quando clica no link, mudando esse valor de `px` vc define onde a ancora deve parar.

**OBS:** *Deixei comentado no código onde vc define a altura em que a ancora deve parar antes do topo da página*

Segue um exemplo prático para vc entender melhor:

```css
/* casso queira abilitar um scroll suave durante a rolagem de tela
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
} */
body {
    min-height: 2000px;
}
    
.content1 {
    height: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#content1, #content2, #content3, #content4  {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -50px; /* esse valor varia de acordo com a altura do seu Header, se ele tiver 200px de altura coloque aqui -220px por exemplo */
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#content1"> CONTEUDO 1</a>
<a href="#content2"> CONTEUDO 2</a>
<a href="#content3"> CONTEUDO 3</a>
<a href="#content4"> CONTEUDO 4</a>

<div id="content1"></div>
<div class="content1">CONTEUDO 1 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content2"></div>
<div class="content1">CONTEUDO 2 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content3"></div>
<div class="content1">CONTEUDO 3 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content4"></div>
<div class="content1">CONTEUDO 4 TEXTO</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente o que pereciso.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues massa jovem, essa técnica é até bem usada, apesar de não seu tão elegante como falei... :D

Comment: A questão é a propriedade CSS que não é tão suportada pelos navegadores: https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

Comment: @DiegoSouza sim Diegão, mas essa propriedade foi apenas um *plus* pra resposta, na verdade ela não tem nada a ver com a solução para a ancoragem. De qualquer forma deixei comentado essa propriedade no CSS, agora ela não faz mais parte da resposta... Se o autor quiser usar basta ele descomentar quando for usar.

Comment: É. Então, é que essa propriedade dá o efeito que o JavaScript faria no caso de browsers mais antigos. O JS poderia server de fallback para o efeito de rolagem suave, caso a propriedade não funcione.

Comment: @DiegoSouza com certeza, fazer um JS como fallback seria o correto mesmo. Mas como não estava dentro do escopo da pergunta é melhor nem usar nada de smooth scroll, vou deixar isso para outra resposta rss

Answer (score 3):

Só sei de um jeito fazendo com Javascript. Estou usando jQuery abaixo para facilitar.

```js
$('.anchor').on('click', function(event){
  
   event.preventDefault();
   
   var section  = $(this).attr('href');
   var top      = $(section).offset().top - 35;
   
   $('html').scrollTop(top);
});
```

```css
.content1{
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#content1" class="anchor"> CONTEUDO 1</a>
<a href="#content2" class="anchor"> CONTEUDO 2</a>
<a href="#content3" class="anchor"> CONTEUDO 3</a>
<a href="#content4" class="anchor"> CONTEUDO 4</a>



<div id="content1" class="content1">CONTEUDO 1 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content2" class="content1">CONTEUDO 2 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content3" class="content1">CONTEUDO 3 TEXTO</div>
<div id="content4" class="content1">CONTEUDO 4 TEXTO</div>
```

Comment: Diego, isso aí está errado. Não é o que ele queria. Acredito que ao invés de + 5 é: - 5.

Comment: Exato, ele tem que parar aparecendo uma parte da div anterior como o @JoãoPedroSchmitz mencionou

Comment: Então é só trocar o operador e o valor, gente.